# DirectoryIndex setting to index.jsp not working as expected

Tags: tomcat, apache

I've got a Tomcat application mounted on /geo and that app has an 'index.jsp' that is accessible directly and works, but when I try to get apache to use it as a directory index entry it never shows up. More odd than this, if I remove the index.html from the DIrectoryIndex line in my httpd configuration, an access of '/' redirects some how to the main tomcat admin page.

Any ideas?

```
JkMount /geo/* worker1
DirectoryIndex /geo/index.jsp index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want your `DirectoryIndex` without the `/geo/`

```
DirectoryIndex index.jsp index.html
```